# Validate all strings

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to prohibit the use of the | character for all strings submitted to my website but I don't want to have to apply a validator attribute to every string property because its unmanageable.

I could validate all strings in a model binder (I'm currently using one to trim all strings) but I don't think that would integrate with the standard validation framework. i.e. generating client side validation.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get this working on the client however I can trap all dodgy strings in a custom model binder and make the form invalid with the following...

```
public class CustomStringModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueResult == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (valueResult.AttemptedValue.Contains("|"))
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "The | character is prohibited.");
        }

        return valueResult.AttemptedValue.Trim();
    }
}
```